# How to get rid of extra height from td?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

My html markup is:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td><span class="test">This is span.</span></td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
```

css is:

```
.test{
  font-size : 12px;
}
```

My span element take a height of 12px. So td should also have a height of 12px. But if I inspect in chrome developers tool, td has a height of 21px. 
`Where is 9px coming from? How to get rid of it?`
 Here is my [code pen](http://codepen.io/gautam/pen/bNdWWw)

Comment: padding :0; margin :0; It doesn't helps.

Answer (score 2):

set `span` to `display:block`

```
.test{
  font-size : 12px;
  display:block;
  background : rgba(255,0,0,.5);
}
```

for removing default margin and padding of all elements use this

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
 }
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
td {
  background: black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.test {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="test">This is span.</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Edit**

the issue is because of `inline-block` one fix is adding `font-size:0;` to parent removes the `white-space`

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/s4ufsbd3/

```
td {
    background: black;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size:0;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
td {
  background: black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}
.test {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="test">This is span.</span><span class="test">This is span.</span>

        <span class="test">This is span.</span>

        <span class="test">This is span.</span>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Making it block does solve the problem, while inline-block doesn't. Sometimes to center the span horizontally, i use inline-block. So cannot use block everytime. How to get rid with inline-block?

Comment: Edited my answer @GautamKumar the issue is because of white-space between `inline-block` adding `font-size:0` to parent fixes the space issue

Comment: the `inline-block` give extra `white-space`

Comment: you will face problems with `font-size:0;`@vitorino-fernandes. Check out my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Vitorino Fernandes solution does work, but you will have issues when you have text inside td since
 `font size  : 0px;`.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>SOME TEXT HERE<span class="test">This is span.</span></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's my css to fix that issue.

```
 td{
     line-height : 0;
  }
 .test{
      font-size : 12px;
      display:inline-block;
       background : rgba(255,0,0,.5);
       line-height : 1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this style to **td** and check `style="line-height : 0;"`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, the line-height is the cause of this space. Also, others suggestions may works as well, but with this you can also adjust the height over and/or bellow the text to your taste using "margin".

**HTML**

```
<table> 
   <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td><p>This is a paragraph. This paragraph is looooooooooooooooong and wants overlap.</p></td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse; /*only if you don't want border space between the cells*/
}
     
td {
  font-size:12px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height:0;
}
p {
  display:block;
  line-height: 1em;
  margin-top: 0px; /*adjust to your necessities*/
  margin-bottom: 0px;  /*adjust to your necessities*/
  }
```